# How to write "decToBin" in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have been looking for an equivalent to JavaScripts `decToBin` in Swift 2. I have not been able to find anything.
I would like to replicate the following JavaScript code code:

```
var max = 511;
var maxlength = decToBin(max).toString().length;
```

Comment: `let maxlength = String(max, radix: 2).characters.count   // 9`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Note: There is no 'decToBin' in ECMAScript. Some library/code is adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String` to achieve this:

```
let max       = 511
let maxlength = String(max, radix: 2).characters.count
```

You can find more in [Apple `String` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html)

Comment: This is a copy paste from my comment

Comment: Look that the posting time is the same, haven't seen yours @LeoDabus

Comment: (Anyone is capable of posting their own answer, if they feel so strongly about such.)